# Multiple jQuery UI sliders, wrong slider is updated

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using jQuery slider for making range sliders. By moving the sliders the corresponding input text field is updated.

The jquery code is:

```
jQuery("form#filterform fieldset.text").each(function(index){

        var this_slider = jQuery(this).find("#slider"); 
        $this_slider = jQuery(this_slider);
        var this_text = jQuery(this).find("input");
        $this_text = jQuery(this_text);

        var this_output = new jQuery(this).find("span#current");
        $this_output = jQuery(this_output);

        $this_slider.empty().slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            values: [0, 100],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
            $this_text.val(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $this_text.val($this_slider.slider("values", 0) + ' - ' + $this_slider.slider("values", 1));
});
```

The problem is, **all sliders update the value of the last generated slider**. Anybody can spot the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you duplicate all your variables with a `$` version of them (*although they all are jquery objects*).

You use those versions in the callback function, and since they are **not declared with the use of `var`** they are global. so they all point to the same thing.. (*namely the last defined*)

you should change the

```
    var this_slider = jQuery(this).find("#slider"); 
    $this_slider = jQuery(this_slider);
    var this_text = jQuery(this).find("input");
    $this_text = jQuery(this_text);

    var this_output = new jQuery(this).find("span#current");
    $this_output = jQuery(this_output);
```

to

```
    var $this_slider = jQuery(this).find("#slider"); 
    var $this_text = jQuery(this).find("input");
    var $this_output = jQuery(this).find("span#current");
```

and it would work ..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm totally new in jQuery (and js in general)

Comment: @Zack, the use of `$` in front of variable names is just for personal convenience. It is not a requirement, nor does it have any effect in the functionality of your code..

Comment: Thanks for that. Found the code somewhere, and I must confess those $ confused me a bit.